# Finding correct entity from datamodel with several foreign key references

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Help needed on accessing correct data model entities in a table generated by Entity framework.

I have a data model that includes tables Message and MessageStatistics. The statistics table has 3 foreign keys to Message table, there are 3 corresponding messages that form a statistics row. Typically they'd be request, acknowledgement and response messages.

In my C# code I need to access the Message objects using their id values, which I can access (like RequestStatistics.RequestMessageId). However, the data model presents Message objects named Message, Message1 and Message2. From these I can't tell by name which object to use, and I don't want to write a function that tests ids of each message.

I can't trust the order of the message objects, so is there a proper way to figure out which message is which?

Answer (score 0):

There are may be problems with data model. You have 3 types of messages: request, acknowledgement and response. It's better to introduce base `Message` class and to inherit other messages' classes from it. Then your MessageStatistics class can have property of that base Message type.

You can read at [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) site about inheritance in Entity Framework (there is description of migrations too) or read about different inheritance implementations - [Mapping the Table-Per-Type (TPT) Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#2.5)  and [Mapping the Table-Per-Concrete Class (TPC) Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#2.6)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm afraid I cannot change the class structure, I must use a edmx data model generated from the db, and I can't touch the db structure. The data model may not be ideal, however there is a Type field in the Messages table that defines which type the message is. In the Statistics table there are foreign keys for each type in each row. I will see if there is something I can use in the links you've provided, thanks for those.